# zenbook ux425e problem with drivers

Tags: release-hera, sound, kernel, resolution

i worked on elementary os hera for a year on old asus laptop- and now i`ve got a new laptop zenbook ux425e.
i downloaded a latest version, installed and updated elementary os  (from app panel and from apt-get)- and there is no video and sound drivers, no sound device and low screen resolution.
googled something about kernel outdate and intel oem inside ubuntu kernel and etc.

so what should i do?

Comment: New laptops usually have poor hardware support. If I were you I would wait a few hours today and then install elementary 6 (which is expected to be announced today). If that is still not enough, you can also install Hardware Enablement Stack with `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.

Comment: Also, you can install drivers from Appcenter (updates tab) directly. It may solve some issues.